# Ignoring nested parts of regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I was hoping to use regular expressions in JS to extract bounded substrings. Specifically, substrings that are bounded by `%{` `}`. For the simple case it is easy enough with `%{.*?}`.

However, I was hoping to be able to ignore nested braces `{}` and strings `""` or `''`.  I know how to get those independently similar to the above regular expression, but I don't know how to combine things meaningfully.

I'd like the hard_string to output `[ "{{friends}} and foes", "cause problems with my '}'s" ]`

```js
let easy_string = "Hello %{world}, I am here to %{cause problems}"
let hard_string = "Hello %{{{friends}} and foes}, I am here to %{cause problems with my '}'s} and {{mustaches}}"

console.log('easy string = ',easy_string.match(/%{.*?}/g).map(s=>s.slice(2,-1)))
console.log('hard string = ',hard_string.match(/%{.*?}/g).map(s=>s.slice(2,-1)))
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `%{(.*?)}(?=[^{}]*%{|$)` https://regex101.com/r/hSIzJq/1 if the curly's do not have to be balanced the the `%{` are not nested

Comment: @Thefourthbird  That is almost perfect (assuming %{ in "" is ignorable) but, it pulls in ```{}```s that follow but are outside of a ```%{}```.  So I guess they do need to be balanced.

Comment: In that case I think you want to match balanced parenthesis right?

Comment: Unless they are inside "" or '', then I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a case where you need to use a parser.

Here is one that matches substrings between `%{` and `}` with anything allowed between `'...'`, `"..."`, and `{...}`:

```js
function splitIt(str) {
  var result = [],
    start = 0,
    level = 0,
    in_quotes = false,
    in_dblquotes = false,
    prcnt_found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    switch (str[i]) {
      case '%':
        if (i + 1 < str.length && str[i + 1] == '{') {
          prcnt_found = true;
          start = i + 2;
        }
        break;
      case '{':
        if (prcnt_found && !in_quotes && !in_dblquotes) {
          ++level
        };
        break;
      case '}':
        if (prcnt_found && level > 0 && !in_quotes && !in_dblquotes) --level;
        if (prcnt_found && level == 0) {
          result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
          prcnt_found = false;
        }
        break;
      case '"':
        if (prcnt_found) {
          in_dblquotes = !in_dblquotes
        }
        break;
      case "'":
        if (prcnt_found) {
          in_quotes = !in_quotes
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var hard_string = "Hello %{{{friends}} and foes}, I am here to %{cause problems with my '}'s} and {{mustaches}}"
console.log(splitIt(hard_string))
```

Comment: This definitely works, thank you for putting this together. 

I do feel a bit guilty seeing the work you put into this.  I did already had a generic parser I was using for this prior to learning about regular expressions this morning. I was hoping there was a shorter, more elegant way to handle this, but I think your assessment of needing a parser is correct. 

This is faster than my parser though, because my parser is generic and needs to run through the code twice in order to work.  Once to block out the quotes, and the other to select the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for all characters `.*` you can ask for "all characters but curly braces":

```regex
/%{([^{}]*)}/g
```

Nested curly braces will simply be ignored. If you need them filtered somehow, you would have to do that separately.

PS: I used https://regexfiddler.com/ to test for your examples and the above seems to work with them.